Is it possible to manually rockface a 1" thick granite stone paver?
I can't find copping stone 1" thick for the stone I want (Banas Stone salt and pepper 1").
I am seeing on youtube masons manually rockfacing 2" stones using a chisel and a hammer.
Would this work with 1" granite stones?

Youtube seldom shows their first/50 tries.

Cant say I understand what you meant

@crip659 means that youtube filmed 50 failures before they had a successful one... and that's the one you saw.  Don't rely too much on youtube.

got it thank you
